# How to Convert a CSV file into a PDF

Tags: python, csv, pdf

I'm currently making a program in python that creates data and then gets stored into a text file. The data is in a column like formation and when i change the file format to csv, it opens LibreOffice Calc (raspberry pi's version of excel) which is exactly how i wanted the data to be formatted.

But i want to take it one step further and convert my CSV file data into a PDF. I've looked on the web and it says how to convert a pdf into a csv which isn't what i want. I also saw something called pyPDF but im not sure about if that would be of any use.

This is the string of data that is being looped 10 times,

```
resultStr = 'Test,{},InNum,{},stats,{},Duration(ms),{} \n'.format("OFF",inPin, result, round(duration*1000))
```

Once the loop finishes, a text file gets opened and the 'resultStr' is the string is getting stored.

Thanks everyone for your help,

~Neamus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [ReportLab](https://www.reportlab.com/), you can programatically generate PDF documents with your data. There are plenty of [examples](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/08/a-simple-step-by-step-reportlab-tutorial/) available to demonstrate the framework and how to use it. In your case, you should simply append to your document story in a loop for each of your CSV result strings.